# JSON add, delete, get

Tags: javascript, json

Can you manipulate a JSON file?

For example could I use a URL to pull an element by its ID say `localhost/text/egg.json?id=1`, or could I delete one of the records from the JSON file using JavaScript? Or is JSON a readonly kind of format?

Comment: You can't. It's not related to JSON, it's about how server and client communicate. You'd have the same problem with XML files. You need server side logic to manipulate the data file. You do not always have a static JSON or XML file, most of the time the data is encoded as such on the fly.

Comment: You need to RTFM on JSON. It's not what you think it is.

Comment: JSON is just a data transfer language, this question involves CRUDing any type of file, the type of file doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

> Can you manipulate a JSON file

In so far as you can manipulate any structured text format

> For example could I use a URL to pull an element by its ID say localhost/text/egg.json?id=1

There is no standard for accessing parts of a JSON text via a URI.

You could write a server side script that returns a JSON text that is a subset of another based on the query string though.

> or could I delete one of the records from the JSON file using JavaScript

You could download the file. Parse it. Delete data form the resulting data structure. Then serialize it back to JSON.

Unless the server supported HTTP PUT or provided some other API for you to send the changed file back, you couldn't save it to the original URI.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. For the JSON itself, you can manipulate it **on the client side** as much as you want. When it comes to modifying it on the server, however the server needs to cooperate. If you have control over the server, you could handle HTTP PUT or POST to change the content of the file. Otherwise, no.